# Facebook Share Dialog not closing after success/cancel

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, xamarin, facebook-share

I managed to integrate Facebook (Xamarin.Facebook.iOS) to my game with custom class (ShareDialog has protected constructor):

```
public class MyShareDialog : Facebook.ShareKit.ShareDialog
    {
        public MyShareDialog() : base(NSObjectFlag.Empty)
        {
        }
    }
```

Then I create and show Dialog:

```
string url = "http://my-url.com/class-to-generate-picture.php?score=" + Board.Score + "&textUp=" + 
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("facebook_I_Scored".Localize());

                var myShareDialog = new MyShareDialog();


                var content = new Facebook.ShareKit.ShareLinkContent {
                    ContentDescription = "facebook_URLTitle".Localize(), 
                    ContentTitle = "facebook_URLDescription1".Localize() + " " + 
                        Board.Score + " " + "facebook_URLDescription2".Localize(), 
                    ImageURL = new NSUrl(url)};
                content.SetContentUrl(new NSUrl("http://my-url.com"));

                myShareDialog.SetShareContent(content);
                myShareDialog.SetDelegate(new MyShareDelegate());

                myShareDialog.Show();
```

Localize() is my extension method to get localized strings (I use this code for Windows and Android, and this extension gives me a comfort of shared code:)).
Board.Score is a static int that contains - yeah - score.

MyShareDelegate:

```
public class MyShareDelegate : Facebook.ShareKit.ISharingDelegate
{
public IntPtr Handle { get; }

    public void DidComplete (Facebook.ShareKit.ISharing sharer, NSDictionary results)
    {
    }

    public void DidFail (Facebook.ShareKit.ISharing sharer, NSError error)
    {
    }

    public void DidCancel (Facebook.ShareKit.ISharing sharer)
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

I have 2 problems:

1. DidComplete/DidFail/DidCancel not being called.
2. Everything works fine, share is being published on timeline BUT after clicking SHARE/CANCEL the dialog is not being closed...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to change `public void` to `public override void`.

2) You need manually call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` after receiving notication

Comment: The override doesn't apply here I think - this is an implementation of interface, not a derrived class. And without working "DidComplete" I don't have a place to put this method...

Comment: I changed MyShareDelegate to:

public class MyShareDelegate : Facebook.ShareKit.SharingDelegate and overrode those methods but still no luck (I try to show UIAlertView after cancel/complete)...

Comment: So after after deleting 'yShareDialog.SetShareContent(content);' there is nothing to share it fails and DidFail is being called.  But still no success with DidComplete/DidCancel...

Comment: @WojGrze Cool, that mean delegates working, and problem are in MyShareDialog setup :)

Comment: Yeah I know, but how do I fix this? :)

Comment: So I managed to make it work, but not the way I hoped. I changed the myShareDialog Mode to ShareDialogMode.FeedWeb. That way I just got a popup, that's automatically closed after share/cancel. I think I will change the mode to "Native" and if it fails show the dialog in FeedWeb mode. That way I "override" the automatic mode... And - of course - nothing is as good as it looks - when deploying to device the app doesn't even start :/ Works fine in simulator

Comment: @WojGrze Glad that you made it :) Maybe you need to setup Facebook in setting on device, so you can use native sharing :)